# X3 AP Saved Game Editor?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I'm looking for a X3 AP saved game editor. my game became modified some how and i was hoping that a saved game editor would help me fix this, i do not want to have to start fresh again after all I've done.

Comment: If you've used mods or cheats, your save game gets the modified flag added to it.  There are certain mods that don't trigger it, but those are direct from Egosoft.

Comment: Either the game holds it's saves in the cloud, or it's somewhere in the steam directory under the name of your account and the name of the game.

Comment: pretty sure its impossible, it wouldn't make sense as egosoft forums allows you to upload unmodified save files to get badges